# Python: Write two lists into two column text file

Tags: list, file, python-3.x

Say I have two lists:
a=[1,2,3]
b=[4,5,6]
I want to write them into a text file such that I obtain a two column text file:

```html
1 4
2 5
3 6
```

Comment: Great, so what's your question?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please consider the possibility to accept one of the answers :)

Answer (score 26):

Simply `zip` the list, and write them to a csv file with tab as the delimiter:

```
>>> a=[1,2,3]
>>> b=[4,5,6]
>>> zip(a,b)
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
>>> import csv
>>> with open('text.csv', 'w') as f:
...    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t')
...    writer.writerows(zip(a,b))
...
>>> quit()
$ cat text.csv
1       4
2       5
3       6
```

Answer (score 20):

You can use [numpy.savetxt()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html), which is a convenient tool from the numpy library.
A minimal example would be as follows:

```
import numpy as np

xarray = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
yarray = np.array([0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50])
# here is your data, in two numpy arrays

data = np.column_stack([xarray, yarray])
datafile_path = "/your/data/output/directory/datafile.txt"
np.savetxt(datafile_path , data, fmt=['%d','%d'])
# here the ascii file is written.
```

The fmt field in np.savetxt() in the example specifies that the numbers are integers.
You can use a different format for each column.
E.g. to specify floating point format, with 2 decimal digits and 10 characters wide columns, you would use `'%10.2f'`.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
file = open("list.txt", "w")
for index in range(len(a)):
    file.write(str(a[index]) + " " + str(b[index]) + "\n")
file.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for this.  It worked great.  But, I don't get why we don't need to include a statement 'for index in range(len(b)):' in order to have it recognize the items from list b that we want to concatenate?

Comment: Very old response. But I think because both lists are of same length.

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution is to write columns of fixed-width text:

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=[4,5,6]

col_format = "{:<5}" * 2 + "\n"   # 2 left-justfied columns with 5 character width

with open("foo.csv", 'w') as of:
    for x in zip(a, b):
        of.write(col_format.format(*x))
```

Then `cat foo.csv` produces:

```
1    4    
2    5    
3    6
```

The output is both human and machine readable, whereas tabs can generate messy looking output if the precision of the values varies along the column.  It also avoids loading the separate `csv` and `numpy` libraries, but works with both lists and arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You can write two lists into a text file that contains two columns.

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=[4,5,6] 
c = [a, b] 
with open("list1.txt", "w") as file:
    for x in zip(*c):
        file.write("{0}\t{1}\n".format(*x))
```

Output in the text file:

```
1   4
2   5
3   6
```

Comment: @just curious to know, what's the meaning of `*` before `c`  and `x`  in your code?

Comment: `a=[1,2,3]
  b=[4,5,6]
  with open("uk.txt", "w") as file:
      for x,y in zip(a,b):
      file.write(f"{x}\t{y}\n")`

Answer (score 0):

It exits a straightway to save and stack same vectors length in columns. To do so use the concatenate function, you can then stack 3,4 or N vectors in columns delimitered by a tab.

```
np.savetxt('experimental_data_%s_%.1fa_%dp.txt'%(signal,angle,p_range), np.c_[DCS_exp, p_exp], delimiter="\t")
```