# Use zip function in python

Tags: python, zip

I have values saved in the file as:

```
[0.        0.5       1.        1.5       2.        2.5000002 .......] [1.00000000e+00 5.32289624e-01 3.31494868e-01 2.17292413e-01 1.46866933e-01 1.01670586e-01......]
```

But i want the values saved as:

```
0.0    1.00000000e+00 

0.5    5.32289624e-01

1.0    3.31494868e-01

1.5    2.17292413e-01

2.0    1.46866933e-01

2.5    1.01670586e-01
```

and hence it will be easily able to plot in the graph.

here is my part of the python code:

```
time = hb_ac.solution['time']
results = hb_ac.solution['results']
tau = hb_ac.solution['tau']
fit=hb_ac.solution['fit']
estimate = hb_ac.solution['estimate']
with open('CaOw2.4dat', 'w') as out:
    out.write("{time} {results}".format(time=time,results=results))
```

Any suggestions on how can i use the zip function here in order to get the output in the desired format.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
time = range(10)
results = range(10,20)

with open('CaOw2.4dat', 'w') as out:
    for t, result in zip(time, results):
        out.write("{time} {results}\n".format(time=t,results=result))
```

File contents:

```
0 10
1 11
2 12
3 13
4 14
5 15
6 16
7 17
8 18
9 19
```

Comment: If you want an extra line between each point, just do `out.write("{time} {results}\n\n".format(time=t,results=result))` !

Comment: No. Actually, i cant modify any part of the code (ie., time=range since it is a module one) and just i want to vales written in the desired format. if i give zip function it is writing the number of times the values are there. But i want it only once.

Comment: Ok, you can try this then: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26082718/python-write-two-lists-into-two-column-text-file