# Split lists by punctuation before writing as columns text file

Tags: python-3.x, list, transpose

Say I have two lists with two initial elements:

```
  a = [Mango, Orange]
```

and

```
  b = [Max - Trom - Tyre | Men, Peter - Min - Mike | Doug]
```

I want to have an output of several columns that looks like:

```
 Mango    Max    Trom  Tyre
 Orange   Peter  Min   Mike
```

In other words, I want to transpose the lists first into two columns and then do the following:

1. Split the second list by '-' into several columns
2. Remove any text after '|' in the second list

I saw this post [Python: Write two lists into two column text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26082718/python-write-two-lists-into-two-column-text-file) but this only enabled me to transpose the  lists and not to split the list elements into several columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help.

**Demo:**

```
a = ["Mango", "Orange"] 
b = ["Max - Trom - Tyre | Men", "Peter - Min - Mike | Doug"]

for i, v in zip(a, b):            #Iterate Both List
    v = v.split("|")[0]           #Split by "|" and access first element
    print([i] + v.split(" - "))   #Form required output.
```

**Output:**

```
['Mango', 'Max', 'Trom', 'Tyre ']
['Orange', 'Peter', 'Min', 'Mike ']
```

Comment: nearly there! how do I then break these list elements into separate columns?

Comment: did not think of that, please edit your answer with code for writing into csv for those who come here from Google. Will accept your answer then.

Answer (score 0):

use below code:

```
a = ['Mango' , 'Orange'] 
b = ['Max - Trom - Tyre | Men' , 'Peter - Min - Mike | Doug']
c=list()
d=list()
for i in range(len(a)):
    d=[]
    d.append(a[i])
    b1=b[i].split("|")[0]
    for k in b1.split("-"):
        d.append(k)

    c.append(d)
    print(c)
```

Comment: nice try but output not as neat as Rakesh's. Moreover, there are repetitions in the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ["Mango", "Orange"]
b = ["Max - Trom - Tyre | Men", "Peter - Min - Mike | Doug"]

def combine_name(key, value):
   return  [key] + [name.strip() for name in value.split("|")[0].split('-')]

print list(map(combine_name, a, b))

>>>[['Mango', 'Max', 'Trom', 'Tyre'], 
    ['Orange', 'Peter', 'Min', 'Mike']]
```